# Why does this Python RegEx pipe not pick out both unicode ranges?

Tags: python, regex, unicode

A sample string containing both hiragana and katakana unicode characters:

```
myString = u"Eliminate ひらがな non-alphabetic カタカナ characters"
```

A pattern to match both ranges, according to:
http://www.rikai.com/library/kanjitables/kanji_codes.unicode.shtml

```
myPattern = u"[\u3041-\u309f]*|[\u30a0-\u30ff]*"
```

Simple Python regex replace function

```
import re
print re.sub(myPattern, "", myString)
```

Returns:

```
Eliminate  non-alphabetic カタカナ characters
```

The only way I can get it to work is if I use the two ranges separately, one after the other. What is stopping this RegEx from simply picking both sides of the |-pipe?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll need to combine the ranges into one character class, otherwise it will match one or the other range, not both:

```
myPattern = u"[\u3041-\u309f\u30a0-\u30ff]*"
```

Demo:

```
>>> myPattern = u"[\u3041-\u309f\u30a0-\u30ff]*"
>>> print re.sub(myPattern, "", u"Eliminate ひらがな non-alphabetic カタカナ characters")
Eliminate  non-alphabetic  characters
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> myPattern = u"[\u3041-\u309f]|[\u30a0-\u30ff]"
>>> print re.sub(myPattern, "", myString)
Eliminate  non-alphabetic  characters
>>>
```

*EDIT* you can combine the two character classes with the OR operator as well

Comment: But it will be slower (albeit not by much) and more verbose than a single class.